# How To Compare Gravitational Time Dilation with Relativistic Time Dilation

Tags: general-relativity, special-relativity

I've been recently introduced to relativity and time dilation and I had the follow question:

If we have 2 objects of equal mass and of equal speed but one is affected by the gravitational pull of a third object, how do we determine what the speed of the object being affected needs to be in order to cancel out the gravitational time dilation caused by the third object so that the clocks on the first and second object are equal?

Sorry if this is an obvious question, my understanding is quite lacking and where I've searched as of yet doesn't seem to help my problem.

Thanks everyone!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I am close to a mass and you are far from the mass, neglecting relative velocity, my clock is slower than yours for you and your clock is the same amount faster for me.

If we have a relative velocity, neglecting gravity, my clock is slower than yours for you and your clock is the same amount slower than mine for me.

Slower+faster can even out, but slower+slower can’t, so I can synchronize your clock with mine, but you can never synchronize my clock with yours.

For a nonrotating mass (read: I’m not in orbit), with you very far away from the mass, the clocks synchronize for me when your velocity as measured in my frame is my own escape velocity.

My answer [here](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/678598/question-about-time-dilation-and-what-an-observer-sees/678609#678609) has a more complete discussion of the relevant formulae.